# going back with the history api (almost working example)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-history

I have a link that I am trying to use the history API with - it is on the index page of my single-page-application:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="logoutlinkdiv">
        <a href = "logout.php" id="logoutlinka">Log out</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click the link, a template is loaded into the `#main` div on my index page - and the URL changes to `xxx/logout.php` as it should. Here is the javascript responsible for the swap:

```
function supports_history_api() {
  return !!(window.history && history.pushState);
}

function swapPage(href) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("GET",
           "templates/" + // ALL MY TEMPLATES ARE IN THIS DIRECTORY
             href.split("/").pop(),
           false);  
  req.send(null);
  if (req.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = req.responseText;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function addClicker(link) {
  link.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (swapPage(link.href)) {
      history.pushState(null, null, link.href);
    }
  }, true);
}

function setupHistoryClicks() {
  addClicker(document.getElementById("logoutlinka"));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    window.onload = function() {
        if (!supports_history_api()) { return; }
        setupHistoryClicks();
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
                swapPage(location.pathname);
            }, false);
        }, 1);
    }
});
```

Everything works going forward, but when I click the back button the templates directory gets loaded into the `#main` div. This happens because `location.pathname` evaluates to `/~Eamon/`, and after the `href.split("/").pop()` - it is just an empty string. Therefore, the templates directory gets loaded because it is the directory pointed to in the `swapPage` function.

Obviously, all I want the program to do when I click the back button is reverse what just happened. In this case, it would mean swapping back in what I had in the `#main` div before the link was clicked. How do I "save" what I had before and load it upon clicking the back button? It may be something as simple as changing the directory structure...but I want my application to be an SPA.

Things I have read on the subject:

1. http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html (this is what I am modeling my code after)
2. http://www.sitepoint.com/an-overview-and-usage-of-javascript-history-api/
3. http://html5doctor.com/history-api/
4. http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introducing-the-html5-history-api/

Comment: Having the same problem. Don't know why it works on the Dive into HTML5 site but not elsewhere.